# ¿Cómo solucionó este problema con PHPMAiler?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy utilizando phpmailer para enviar un correo de restablecimiento de contraseña, pero al parecer no envía no sé cual puede ser la razón, según lo que veo dice que el usuario y contraseña son incorrectos, pero están bien, así qué estoy igual, este es el error que se genera:

```
2019-12-03 15:08:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials s124sm917226vkb.42 - gsmtp 
2019-12-03 15:08:53 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. 
Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials s124sm917226vkb.42 - gsmtp 
2019-12-03 15:08:53 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 
2019-12-03 15:08:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2019-12-03 15:08:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection s124sm917226vkb.42 - gsmtp 
2019-12-03 15:08:53 SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Este es el código que estoy realizando:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["login"])){            
                    $this->menu();
                    return;            
            }
            $userMail = "correo@gmail.com";
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com; smtl.live.com';
            $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;    
            $mail->Username = $userMail;
            $mail->Password = "***********";
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->setFrom($userMail, "Empresa SA");
            $mail->addReplyTo($userMail, "Empresa SA");        
            $mail->addAddress($correo);
            $message = utf8_decode(file_get_contents("../views/administrador/templateEmail.html"));
            $message = str_replace('{{codigo}}', $codigo, $message);
            $mail->isHTML(true);

            $mail->Subject = "Solicitud para restablecer clave";
            $mail->msgHTML($message);     
            $mail->send();
```

Comment: Activaste el acceso en la cuenta de GMAIL para utilizar el smtp? prueba solo con smtp.gmail.com. El usuario smtp de google es el correo, incluyendo @gmail.com

Comment: Sí, según yo ha de ser un problema con el servidor, pero no sé exactamente qué, en el local me funciona normal